# How to clear floated unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list menu that is floating left. I can't get the menu's containing div (#header) to fully wrap around it. Here's an example of what I have..

html

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="menuCont">
        <ul id="ccMenu">
            <li>Misc</li>
            <li>Web</li>
            <li>Zero</li>
            <li>Whole</li>
            <li>Retail</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="body"></div>
```

css

```
#header {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#menuCont {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#body {
   width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    clear: left;
}
#ccMenu {
    width: 400px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#ccMenu li {
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5M6vw/)

I believe I got #body div to clear properly, but I can't get #header to wrap around the menu; it just floats beneath its border. Could I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to add `overflow: hidden;` to `#header`

http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/5M6vw/1/

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:auto` to `#header` and that will do the trick.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5M6vw/2/)**

Comment: This works, but gives me stupid vertical scrollbar in my actual app (though not in jsfiddle). Not sure why, as I have no vertical limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Float the #header container and the #menuCont container left also:

http://jsfiddle.net/tahdhaze09/dX7Bm/

```
#header {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;
}
#menuCont {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:left;
}
#body {
   width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    clear: left;
}
#ccMenu {
    width: 400px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#ccMenu li {
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the header div to floated left. I want it centered.

Comment: Technically, you're not centering the div with the CSS you have. You'd like the whole layout centered? If you float the contents of a div, the container will collapse. The other option is to give #menuCont height to contain the menu. I edited the jsfiddle, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/tahdhaze09/dX7Bm/1/

Comment: Oh, yeah I just noticed I didn't center the div in my demo. Sorry about that.